# Centralized exception handling across applications in .Net

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, exception, msmq

I need your support and suggestions to find solution in my situation.

- We have many applications (Web, Win Service, WCF, Win App, ...) hosted on many servers.
- Every application handles and logs exception by itself.
- I need to centralize and unify the exception handling across applications by passing the exception to (WCF, Web Service or MSMQ).

**My Attempts**

- **WCF:** I can't serialize exception object from client to service.
- **Web Method:** the same as my WCF attempt above.
- **MSMQ:** I can serialize the exception object but i lose the `TargetSite` property that holds method reflection.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try serializing the `Exception` to a binary stream via `BinaryFormatter` then plonk that into a `byte[]` property of your `DataContract` class?

Comment: Why can't you serialize exception? Has the server all exception types which exists on clients?

Comment: @MickyDuncan  thanks for your response, I tried the solution that you suggest form me in MSMQ and I lose TargetSite info while de-serializing

Comment: OK then, sorry can't think of anything else sadly.

Comment: How would you _expect_ TargetSite to work with a serialized exception? It's a 'reference to the MethodBase that threw the current exception' - and the class containing the method that threw the current exception is not going to be present in your centralized error handler. Note the remarks in the documentation: "If the method that throws this exception is not available and the stack trace is not a null reference TargetSite obtains the method from the stack trace. If the stack trace is a null reference, TargetSite also returns a null reference."

Comment: Look at http://logstash.net/